# Dual norm of $\ell_{1,\infty}$ matrix norm

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, matrix-norms

Given a matrix $X$, define the $\ell_{1,\infty}$ norm:

$$ \|X\|_{1,\infty} = \sum_i \max_j |X_{ij}| $$

Can I get its dual norm with the following definition of dual norm?

$$ \|Z\|_{1,\infty}^*: = \max_X \left\{ \left<Z,X\right>, \text{s.t.} \|X\|_{1,\infty} \leq 1 \right\}.$$

Does its dual norm have an explicit expression? Say, like the dual norm of the $\ell_1$ norm is the $\ell_\infty$ norm?

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of the dual norm.

Comment: Actually I want to know  whether its dual norm has an explicit expression? like the dual norm of $\ell_1$ norm is $\ell_\infty$ norm.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the $\ell_{\infty ,1}$ norm is the dual?